# iOS - Accessing photos from Google Drive account using Objective C

Tags: ios, google-photos

I am working on an application which needs access to Google Photos from Google Drive.

Is it possible to access it?

I am not referring to the images from the My Drive in Google Drive.

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Yes, google photos can be accessed using picasa web albums

Comment: So I have to use picasa for access photos in ios App?

Comment: Yes, https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/code, This link will help you

Comment: OK Thanks let me check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible please check below link i have updated my answer, you can also fetch photos from google drive like this

```
GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList query];
    query.q = @"mimeType='image/jpeg'";
    query.spaces = @"photos";
    query.pageSize = 200;
    query.fields = @"nextPageToken,files(id,name,mimeType,thumbnailLink,originalFilename)";
    [self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                         GTLRDrive_FileList *result, NSError *error)
```

For full details check below link.

[Fetching Photos from google photos Objective c [iOS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929139/fetching-photos-from-google-photos-objective-c-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Google haven't made it public yet.
Checked on www.programmableweb.com