# Regarding Picasa webalbum iOS

Tags: ios, picasa

Hi right now i am fetching photos from google photos[Picasa WebAlbums]. I have checked few stackoverflow questions and many ways to fetch my google photos, where i have came across one link which is attached below.

[Google Plus API & photos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831277/google-plus-api-photos?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I can see all photos from below user but i cant see my photos when i pass my user_id by replacing his user_id.I can see only my profile Pic.

https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/115999964287637644901

Comment: I found it finally and i made step by step answer to fetch google photos from google drive instead of picasa webalbums, hopefully this answer will help someone in future.   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929139/fetching-photos-from-google-photos-objective-c-ios